# Batch File - To Find and Uninstall any existance µTorrent.exe on a PC

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, scripting, uninstallation

I am new here and I am some what of a novice in batch.

I manage about 10,000 PC's via Microsoft InTune and I have found that around 500 of them have uTorrent installed and I need to remove it because of uTorrent's capabilities and security risk.

Basically what I am wanting to do is search the entire C:/ Drive for the "µTorrent.exe", Find it, Uninstall it, Delete any existence that it was ever there and keep looping through until all of the µTorrent related files are deleted. And Possibly remove any entry from the registry if possible.

I can run all of these commands in A CMD window just fine, so I am thinking it is a format error, so when trying to compile them all in batch it doesn't seem to complete after the:

.

```
Call %p% /Uninstall /S /Q 
Echo %p%
```

.

Then it fails.

.

BTW I can not use WMIC to uninstall the software because of where uTorrent installs itself.

.

I am going to post a little info I have found on the subject:

HKCU\Software\uTorrent

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\µTorrent
µTorrent /forceuninstall

Display Name: µTorrent

Version: 3.4.5.41628

Install Location:%APPDATA%\Roaming\uTorrent

Publisher: Bit Torrent Inc.

**Uninstall String: "%APPDATA%\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe" /UNINSTALL**

Registry Location: Computer\HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\µTorrent

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\uTorrent

File location of uTorrent.exe C:\Users\Cricketadmin\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent

Remove for uTorrent client: Delete the exe: 
delete users\%*Users*\appdata\roaming\utorrent

C:/%USER%\AppData\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe
C:\Program Files\uTorrent\utorrent.exe

.

Dir /S C:*µTorrent.exe    <--- will display any instance of µTorrent.exe on the entire c:/

.

Below I have posted what I have compiled so far:

.

```
@echo OFF
CLS
TITLE Find and Uninstall µTorrent.exe
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
REM This Batch Program will Find and Uninstall µTorrent.exe
GoTo :LOOP1
:LOOP1
REM This loop will search all of the C:/ to find the "µTorrent.exe" file, and Uninstall "µTorrent.exe" if found.
For /R C:\ %%A IN (*) Do IF "%%~nxA"=="utorrent.exe" Set p=%%~dpnxA
IF DEFINED p (
    Echo %p%
    Call %p% /Uninstall /S /Q 
    Echo %p%
    DEL /F /S /Q %p%
    Echo %p%
    GoTo :LOOP1
) Else (
    Echo File not found & EXIT CMD
    GoTo :LOOP2
)
:LOOP2
REM This loop will end the batch!
IF NOT EXIST %p% (
    Echo %p% File not found & EXIT CMD
) ELSE (
    Echo %p% 
)
ENDLocal
EXIST /B
EXIT Errorlevel
END

REM I also need to be able to delete the desktop icon <- this is a reminder to me.

REM I would like to some how incorporate "Dir /S C:\*ipscan24.exe" into this Batch Script and use the results as a Variable(s).
```

Comment: Just put this in a batch file `"%APPDATA%\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe" /UNINSTALL`. That's all you need do - it will uninstall or fail. If you care if there's nothing to uninstall try `"%APPDATA%\Roaming\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe" /UNINSTALL && Echo Uninstalled || Echo Wasn't Installed`

Answer (score 0):

```
Call %p% /Uninstall /S /Q
```

should be

```
Call "%p%" /Uninstall /S /Q
```

to guard against separators in `%p%` (like spaces....)

```
) Else (
    Echo File not found & EXIT CMD
    GoTo :LOOP2
)
```

This will execute an `exit` command and terminate this `cmd` instance - unless it objects to the `cmd` part (which is intended to do what?) under which circumstance it would generate an error message.

Point is, the `goto` will not be executed, as the `cmd` session will terminate

```
IF NOT EXIST %p% (
```

should be

```
IF NOT EXIST "%p%" (
```

same `in case of separators` reason.

```
EXIST /B
EXIT Errorlevel
END
```

These three lines make little sense. `exist` is not a standard command (unless it is some known executable). `exit errorlevel` is probably meant to return the errorlevel to whatever has called this routine. It should be

```
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

`end` is not a valid standard command, and would not be executed in any case since the previous command is `exit`.

Oh - btw:

```
del /s c:\utorrent.exe /q /f
```

would delete all `utorrent.exe` files on `c:`. Use with **extreme caution** since a small tyop could have bad consequences.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the below Script and it will completely removed any trace of the Software uTorrent.

```
@Echo Off
CLS
TITLE Find and Uninstall Bad SoftWare
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
:Part1
SET "BAD=µTorrent.exe"
SET "Z="
For /f "delims=" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S "C:\*uTorrent.exe" 2^>NUL') Do Set Z=%%A
IF DEFINED Z (
GoTo :Part2
) Else (
GoTo :Part2
)
GoTo :Part2
:Part2
IF DEFINED Z (
"!Z!" /UNINSTALL /S >nul 2>&1
GoTo :Part1
) ELSE (
GoTo :Part3
)
GoTo :Part3
:Part3
SET "Z="
For /F "delims=" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S "C:\*Torrent*" 2^>NUL') Do Set Z=%%A
IF DEFINED Z (
Del /F /S /Q "!Z!" >nul 2>&1
RD /S /Q "!Z!" >nul 2>&1
GoTo :Part3
) Else (
GoTo :Part4
)
GoTo :Part4
:Part4
ChDir /D C:\
For /F "delims=" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S "C:\users\*.TMP*" 2^>NUL') Do (
Del /F /S /Q "%%A" >nul 2>&1
)
ChDir /D C:\
For /F "delims=" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S "C:\Windows\*.TMP*" 2^>NUL') Do (
Del /F /S /Q "%%A" >nul 2>&1
)
ChDir /D C:\
For /F "delims=" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S "C:\*.TMP*" 2^>NUL') Do (
Del /F /S /Q "%%A" >nul 2>&1
)
ChDir /D C:\
For /F "delims=" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S "C:\Windows\Temp\*.*" 2^>NUL') DO (
Del /F /S /Q "%%A" >nul 2>&1
RD /S /Q "C:\Windows\Temp\" >nul 2>&1
)
ChDir /D C:\
For /F "delims=" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S "C:\Windows\Prefetch\*.*" 2^>NUL') DO (
Del /F /S /Q "%%A" >nul 2>&1
RD /S /Q "C:\Windows\Prefetch\" >nul 2>&1
)
ChDir /D C:\
For /F "delims=" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S ^"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\*.*^" 2^>NUL') DO (
Del /F /S /Q "%%A" >nul 2>&1
RD /S /Q "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\" >nul 2>&1
)
ChDir /D C:\
For /F "delims=" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S "C:\%temp%" 2^>NUL') DO (
Del /F /S /Q "%%A" >nul 2>&1
RD /S /Q "C:\TEMP\" >nul 2>&1
)
ChDir /D C:\
DEL /F /S /Q %temp%\ >nul 2>&1
ChDir /D C:\
For /F "delims=" %%A IN ('Dir /B /S "C:\*.TMP*" 2^>NUL') DO (
Del /F /S /Q "%%A" >nul 2>&1
)
ChDir /D C:\
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8 >nul 2>&1
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2 >nul 2>&1
:Part5
SET "R="
For /F "delims=" %%B IN ('Dir /B /S "C:\$Recycle.Bin\*" 2^>NUL') Do Set R=%%B
IF DEFINED R (
Del /F /S /Q "!R!" >nul 2>&1
RD /S /Q "!R!" >nul 2>&1
GoTo :Part5
) Else (
GoTo :Part6
)
:Part6
Set "RegKey=HKCR"
Set "SearchWord=*Torrent*"
For /F "tokens=*" %%A In ('REG QUERY "%RegKey%" /F "%SearchWord%" /S ^| Find /I "Key" ^| Sort') Do (
For /F "tokens=* delims= " %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "Name=%%B"
Set "Name=!Name!"
For /F "delims=@" %%B In ("!Name!") Do (
    REG DELETE "!Name!" /F >nul 2>&1
)
)
GoTo :Part7
:Part7
Set "RegKey=HKCU"
Set "SearchWord=*Torrent*"
For /F "tokens=*" %%A In ('REG QUERY "%RegKey%" /F "%SearchWord%" /S ^| Find /I "Key" ^| Sort') Do (
For /F "tokens=* delims= " %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "Name=%%B"
Set "Name=!Name!"
For /F "delims=@" %%B In ("!Name!") Do (
    REG DELETE "!Name!" /F >nul 2>&1
)
)
GoTo :Part8
:Part8
Set "RegKey=HKLM"
Set "SearchWord=*Torrent*"
For /F "tokens=*" %%A In ('REG QUERY "%RegKey%" /F "%SearchWord%" /S ^| Find /I "Key" ^| Sort') Do (
For /F "tokens=* delims= " %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "Name=%%B"
Set "Name=!Name!"
For /F "delims=@" %%B In ("!Name!") Do (
    REG DELETE "!Name!" /F >nul 2>&1
)
)
GoTo :Part9
:Part9
Set "RegKey=HKU"
Set "SearchWord=*Torrent*"
For /F "tokens=*" %%A In ('REG QUERY "%RegKey%" /F "%SearchWord%" /S ^| Find /I "Key" ^| Sort') Do (
For /F "tokens=* delims= " %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "Name=%%B"
Set "Name=!Name!"
For /F "delims=@" %%B In ("!Name!") Do (
    REG DELETE "!Name!" /F >nul 2>&1
)
)
GoTo :Part10
:Part10
Set "RegKey=HKCC"
Set "SearchWord=*Torrent*"
For /F "tokens=*" %%A In ('REG QUERY "%RegKey%" /F "%SearchWord%" /S ^| Find /I "Key" ^| Sort') Do (
For /F "tokens=* delims= " %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "Name=%%B"
Set "Name=!Name!"
For /F "delims=@" %%B In ("!Name!") Do (
    REG DELETE "!Name!" /F >nul 2>&1
)
)
GoTo :Part11
:Part11
ENDLocal
Exit /b %errorlevel%
END
```

The END

Comment: There are comments about problems with this script here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6950&p=45650#p45650